# how to dynamic route in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

hello I have a problem with the dynamic router
it's my router code

```
<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`/dashboard/buyList`} component={BuyList} />
        <Route path={`/dashboard/receipt`} component={WarehouseReceipt} />
        <Route path='/dashboard/new' component={NewBuy} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/buyList:id' component={BuyInfo}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashboardDetail} exact/>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

my problem is where how I must set buyList:id and define it in my project?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and what the issue is? If you are just asking how to link to the path, just render a `Link` component or use a `history.push` to "/dashboard/buyList123" or similar. Are you sure you didn't mean to add a path separator to the route, i.e. `path='/dashboard/buyList/:id'` instead of `path='/dashboard/buyList:id'`?

Comment: hes asking about nested routes

Comment: thanks for your help, yes I want to have a path like this buyList:id but I don't know how to react to understand the id of a product and must show it?

Comment: Can you share with us where you are linking to your routes? If you've set up the routes and links correctly, the `Router` will rerender with the updated URL and render the appropriate route.

Comment: @AshishKamble Linking can be from *anywhere* within a routing context. How about we wait for OP to state the issue and include all the relevant code before we start making assumptions about what they need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is small example how it works in nested routes,

```
function BuyList () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>BuyList</h1>
      <ul>
        {buyList.map(({ name, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`/buylist/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`/buylist/:id`}>
        <Buy />
      </Route>
    </div>
  )
}
```

with react hook,

```
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={path}>
      <h3>Please select a buy.</h3>
    </Route>
    <Route path={`${path}/:buyId`}>
      <Buy />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

and Buy is,

```
function Buy() {

  let { buyId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{buyId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```